# Supabase and Stripe Customer ID with RLS

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, supabase

In a NextJS project I'm trying to add a stripe_customer_id to a Supabase user when they first sign up.

I can get this working fine when RLS **isn't** enabled but I need RLS to hide user data from anyone who isn't authenticated.

Can anyone help with what RLS policy I need to write to allow the create-stripe-customer api to update the customer_id column in Supabase?

Below is the create-stripe-customer (the file that works when RLS isn't enabled but not when RLS is enabled)

```
import initStripe from "stripe";
import { supabase } from "../../utils/supabaseClient";

const handler = async (req, res) => {

  if (req.query.API_ROUTE_SECRET !== process.env.API_ROUTE_SECRET) {
    return res.status(401).send('You are not authorized to call the API');
  }

  const stripe = initStripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: req.body.record.email,
  });

  console.log("REQUEST-", req.body.record.id);
  console.log("CUST ID-", customer.id);

  await supabase
    .from("profiles")
    .update({
      stripe_customer: customer.id,
    })
    .eq("id", req.body.record.id);

  res.send({ message: `stripe customer creaded: ${customer.id}` });

  console.log("TESTTESTTEST");
};

export default handler;
```

Answer (score 1):

When updating data on Supabase, using the service role key instead of the anon key to create Supabase client will allow you to bypass row-level security policies.

You can find your service role key just below your anon key in your Supabase dashboard. Here is a video explaining how to use service role key to bypass RLS.
https://egghead.io/lessons/supabase-use-the-supabase-service-key-to-bypass-row-level-security

Comment: Yeah I've done this lesson but my request is still empty when logging in.

When the create-stipe-customer API runs the req.body is empty - I might have narrowed it down to the fact I'm using magic link to log in but I'm really not sure.

Comment: @SamDonaghy-Bell Are you using the Service key instead of the anon key when making request to Supabase from your function? As long as you are using the service key, how you login will not matter, because requests made using the service key bypasses RLS.

Comment: I believe I am yes.  I think I've narrowed things down a little more.  I can create the stripe_customer when sending the request via thunderclient or postman but when the request is made automatically when a new user is created my request body is totally empty..

Answer (score 1):

To append to this, you should store the Stripe customer ID in a private table that only your `SERVICE_ROLE` key can access. The client-side, even if the user is authenticated, should never be able to modify this, as they could change their own customer ID.

So make sure to store this in a secure table that only your server-side code can access.

Create a private mapping table: https://github.com/vercel/nextjs-subscription-payments/blob/main/schema.sql#L34-L45

```sql
/**
* CUSTOMERS
* Note: this is a private table that contains a mapping of user IDs to Stripe customer IDs.
*/
create table customers (
  -- UUID from auth.users
  id uuid references auth.users not null primary key,
  -- The user's customer ID in Stripe. User must not be able to update this.
  stripe_customer_id text
);
alter table customers enable row level security;
-- No policies as this is a private table that the user must not have access to.
```

Use your `SERVICE_ROLE` key in a secure server side environment to access this private table: https://github.com/vercel/nextjs-subscription-payments/blob/main/utils/supabase-admin.ts#L7-L12

```js
// Note: supabaseAdmin uses the SERVICE_ROLE_KEY which you must only use in a secure server-side context
// as it has admin priviliges and overwrites RLS policies!
const supabaseAdmin = createClient(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL || '',
  process.env.SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY || ''
);
```